# Reading URL parameters through TCP socket connection

Tags: c++, sockets, https

I'm listening on a TCP socket on *localhost* and printing what I receive (simplified code):

```cpp
auto listener = sockets::listen_at(L"127.0.0.1", 11235);
auto client = sockets::accept_connection_from(listener);

static constexpr int BUFFER_SIZE = 0xFFU;
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]{};

std::string data;
while (auto received = sockets::receive_data_from(client, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE))
    data.append(buffer, received);

std::string dump;
for (auto& c : data)
    dump.append(std::format("{:x}", unsigned(c)));

std::cout << dump;

sockets::close_socket(client);
sockets::close_socket(listener);
```

While listening at `127.0.0.1:11235` I open a web browser and type `https://localhost:11235/x&code=000000000000`, I was expeting to receive the *HTTP negotiation*, specifically the [Accept header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation#The_Accept_header):

> ##### The Accept header
>
> The Accept header lists the MIME types of media resources that the agent is willing to process. This is a comma-separated list of MIME types, each combined with a quality factor, a parameter that indicates the relative degree of preference between the different MIME types.

But I'm receiving data that I'm assuming is not random:

```
0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF -- Test 1
————————————————————————————————
a53c85cffffffe1fffffff2ffffffdfd
ffffffd2521101700012000230002d02
1101b03202ffffffff10104469050326
8327a7a0100150ffffffce0000000000
… 192 bytes …
0000

0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF -- Test 2
————————————————————————————————
163120101fffffffc3338fffffff064f
fffff98ffffff8515ffffff9077fffff
fc8ffffff89ffffffbcffffffa03efff
fffceffffffecffffff904cffffff98f
… 960 bytes …
0000000000

0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF -- Test 3
————————————————————————————————
163120101fffffffc332bffffffc3fff
fffeefffffff9bffffffb1ffffffbdff
fffff32f2f42ffffffc71ffffff9dfff
fffbd2b60ffffffaeffffffc8ffffffb
… 928 bytes …
0000000000000000
```

- What is this data the browser is sending to me?
- Is there a way to extract the URL parameters from a connection from the browser to my socket?

Comment: You forgot about TLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is this data the browser is sending to me?

The beginning of the TLS handshake (specifically the ClientHello).

> Is there a way to extract the URL parameters from a connection from the browser to my socket?

If you want to get the HTTP request without implementing TLS in your server, you have to use plain HTTP with an `http://` URL instead of using HTTPS (HTTP over TLS) with an `https://` URL.